# Dependency injection with runtime parameters in the constructor

Tags: c#

I started to implement a console app and learning about DI and IOC.

So I decided to write two class

```
public class Reporter {
        public readonly IDataExport exporter;
        public readonly IService service;
    
        Reporter(IService service, IDataExport export ) {
        service = service;
        exporter = exporter;
    } 

    public void Run() {
       var data = service.GetData();
       exporter.Export(data);
    } 

}
```

The exporter is defined as

```
  public class CsvExporter : IDataExport {
        public readonly StreamWriter writter;
        
          CsvExporter(StreamWriter writer) {
        writer = writer;
        } 
    
     
     //interface implementation
     public async Task Export(IEnumerable<Person> data) 
    {
       var formmatedData = FormartData(data) 
       await writer.WriteAsync(formattedData);
       await writer.FlushAsync();
    } 
 }
```

My question is how can I handle the IOC if I have to work with the StreamWriter that needs to write a csv and the filename has to be passed as a parameter in runtime

Kind regards and thanks

Comment: I can use some kind of [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) here with api like `Factory.GetExporter(ExporterTYpe.Csv, stream)` and create exporter by hand there, not via DI, and inject/resolve the factory. Or just add the `stream` as parameter to `IDataExport.Export`

Comment: Also from the code it is not very clear where do you create the stream itslef.

Comment: I believe that the best approach is to pass StreamWriter as a parameter to the method otherwise you would have to use Factory Patterns as other fellows said here. Sometimes rely on Factory and at the same use an Injector tool can become a nightmare, believe me, I've been there

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to solve this is with a factory. There are many ways to construct this, this is just one example:

```
public interface IDataExportFactory{
     IDataExport Create(Stream stream);
}
```

Another option would be to move the parameter to the method

```
public async Task Export(IEnumerable<Person> data, Stream stream)
```

For this rather simple example both alternatives are very similar. The former may be better if you have a large interface that that can export different kinds of data, or do more things.

I would recommend using `Stream` instead of `StreamWriter`, since the former is more general.

If you need the exporter to be oblivious to the export-destination you could inject a instance of CsvWriter that already have the stream, or have some means of acquiring a stream. But it is unclear from the question exactly what component should be responsible for creating the stream, or if all exporters are expected to be able to write to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a an IoC container that supports **method injection** like autoface ([docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html)) you can use it to inject the `Stream` outside of the class scope, and then let some other class to be responsible for initiating the `Stream` object:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<WriterService>().As<IWriterService>();
builder.RegisterType<CsvExporter>()
    .OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs<CsvExporter> e) =>
    {
        var stream = e.Context.Resolve<IWriterService>(); --> runtime resolving!!
        e.Instance.SetStream(stream);
    });
```

And modify your class to have a `SetStream` method:

```
public class CsvExporter : IDataExport {
    private Stream _writter;
    
    SetStream(Stream writer) {
        this._writer = writer;
    }
 
    //interface implementation
    public async Task Export(IEnumerable<Person> data) 
    {
        var formmatedData = FormartData(data) 
        await this._writer.WriteAsync(formattedData);
        await this._writer.FlushAsync();
    } 
}
```